# Cannot find button element C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Selenium cannot find the element "Log in". I looked through the other stackoverflow questions regarding this and didn't seem to completely resolve.

```
// C#
IWebElement submit = driver.FindElement(By.Name("Log in"));
submit.Click();

// html
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<button class="btn btn-success shadow" type="submit">Log in</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit'][text()='Log in']")`

Comment: What if later or the rest of the page has more buttons that can submit. That would bring back 1+.

Comment: perfect, don't have access to set the name attribute

Comment: LULZ, tell your dev's to always provide IDs for there elements so the testers can test. I am a dev I always provide IDs for my testers.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey You're right about more than one button and th id's. But it's always possible to write more complex locator to make it unique. BTW, this one `//button[@type='submit'][text()='Log in']` should work too

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich yep that's cool. I would modify the answer you gave to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You never set the button name attribute.

```
<button class="btn btn-success shadow" type="submit" name="Log in">Log in</button>
```