# Protractor-net NgBy. missing some locators

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, protractor-net

I am using Visual Studio 2015 as my IDE and 
I installed protractor(version 0.10.2) to my project.
In my code below
      `[TestMethod]
        public void Login()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            var ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
            ngDriver.Url = "https://weather.com";
            ngDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("user-login")).Click();`
Now, I want to locate a 'Log In' button using buttonText locator.
However, when I tried `ngDriver.FindElement(NgBy.)`, only following options were displayed after NgBy.:
Binding,
Equals,
ExactBinding,
ExactRepeater,
Model,
ReferenceEquals,
Repeater,
SelectedOpion

When I tried this with WebStorm and Javascript,
I was able to locate and work with button as below 
element(by.buttonText('Log In')).click();

Why isn't something like 'ButtonText' appear after NgBy.?

Even in [Anthony Chu's blog](http://anthonychu.ca/post/end-to-end-testing-angular-apps-with-nunit-and-specflow-using-protractornet/), he is using Ngby.Input(), which I don't have in the list. Why am I missing all these locators?

---

I found that NgBy class under Protractor offers only followings:
[class NgBy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dixDw.jpg)

so maybe Protractor-net doesn't provide NgBy.ButtonText()?
But it doesn't make sense to me. I think that I am still doing something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

See comments from this pull request :
https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net/pull/22

Comment: That discussion does not explain the missing NgBys. As JP-3 mentions in his last comment, those methods are [part of the original protractor project](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/locators.ts) and it is questionable IMO to decide to not include them in the .Net port.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in the "main" Protractor-net fork (maintained by bbaia) some NgBys are missing when comparing to the original Protractor project.

**Option1**

You can usually instead use the normal .Net WebDriver By (e.g. XPath or CssSelector) to locate the elements:

[Find button by inner text with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304084/webdriver-c-find-button-presumably-by-text)

[Find button by attribute value and text with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843878/cannot-find-button-element-c-sharp)

You may also find this valuable -
[Find element by case insensitive text with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674093/find-element-by-xpath-which-contains-text)

**Option2**

You can also write your own implementation using something like 

`driver.FindElements(By.TagName("button")).Where(e => e.Text.Trim() == "Text").FirstOrDefault();`

Note that in many cases this is much slower than using XPath though.

**Option3**

If, because you are porting code that is already using those methods, it is important to you to have them, you can try sergueik fork which does have the missing methods:
https://github.com/sergueik/protractor-net

Note that it is further behind the main fork though - https://github.com/sergueik/protractor-net/network

Comment: Thanks Ory. I know it's a bit late. :)